# Stop re-renders for other similar component in FlatList

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am dynamically adding similar components into a FlatList. Each component has a button where the default text is hard-coded, whereas when the user presses the button, a modal to pick time pops up. When i click the button that adds another of the same component, the previous component re-renders and sets back its default hard-coded text. How do i prevent re-renders of previous components?

I've tried setting another prop `extraData` as suggested from other SO answers to somewhat similar questions. But i can't get the expected behaviour.

***The custom component is in a separate file.***

Here is my FlatList:

```js
const [setElements, elements] = useState([]);
const [dailyIndex, setDailyIndex] = useState(0);

const addElements = () => {
  setElements([...elements, addElementItem()]);
  setDailyIndex(prevState => prevState.dailyIndex + 1);
};

const addElementItem = index => <ElementItem elementKey={index} />;

<FlatList
  extraData={dailyIndex}
  data={elements}
  renderItem={({ item, index }) => addElementItem(index)}
  numColumns={2}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
/>;
```

And my custom Component:

```js
const ElementItem = props => {
  return (
    <Layout key={props.keyElement}>
      <Layout>
        <Button onPress={showTimeHandler}>{time ? button_time : 'TIME'}</Button>
        <TimePickerModal
          mode='time'
          isVisible={isTimePickerVisible}
          onConfirm={onTimeChangeHandler}
          onCancel={showTimeHandler}
          date={new Date(new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0))}
        />
      </Layout>
    </Layout>
  );
};
```

As suggested below, i used memo but it still re-renders the rest of the components in the FlatList

```js
const ElementItem = memo(props => {
  return (
    <Layout key={props.keyElement}>
      <Layout>
        <Button onPress={showTimeHandler}>{time ? button_time : 'TIME'}</Button>
        <TimePickerModal
          mode='time'
          isVisible={isTimePickerVisible}
          onConfirm={onTimeChangeHandler}
          onCancel={showTimeHandler}
          date={new Date(new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0))}
        />
      </Layout>
    </Layout>
  );
}, (prevProps, nextProps) => prevProps.keyElement === nextProps.keyElement);
```

Photos to illustrate:

When i click on the add button and select a time

[image: first cut]

When i click on the add button again

[image: second cut]

Appreciate all the help.

Comment: That is a weird way to add elements. Better just save their details instead of the components themselves and then pass those details when rendering components. t's much easier to compare the details than the actual components.

Comment: hey thanks for your input! what i intend to do is to store the timings added into an array. i could possibly work with what you suggested instead.. i think that'll be simpler. cheers @Clarity!

Answer (score 0):

Use `memo` with functional components:

```js
import React, { memo } from 'react';

// ‍♀️
const ComponentB = (props) => {
  return <div>{props.propB}</div>
};

// ‍♂️
const ComponentB = memo((props) => {
  return <div>{props.propB}</div>
});
```

That’s it! You just need to wrap `<ComponentB>` with a `memo()` function. Now it will only re-render when `propB` actually changes value regardless of how many times its parent re-renders!

For more information please visit https://alligator.io/react/keep-react-fast/#use-memo-and-purecomponent

Comment: i actually tried using memo too, but i removed it for this post as it didnt really work. i may be using it the wrong way.. i'll try again. also, the custom component is in a different file

Comment: hi, i updated my question above with `memo`, but the rest of the elements in the flatlist still re-renders.

Comment: Then must be some data is changing. As per documentation, It will only re-render when its value changed.

Comment: yes that is correct. so any change of data specifically from the docs - `extraData` prop will cause the entire flatlist to re-render. my issue is adding new elements causes other previous elements to re-render.